# How to get a multidimensional post value via typoscript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

In TYPO3 4.5, how can a value stored in $_POST (in a 2-dimensional array) be accessed via Typoscript?

print_r($_POST) looks like this:

[image]

I have tried this:

```
20 = TEXT
20.data = GP:[tx_powermail_pi1][uid1517]
```

and also

```
20.value.data = GP:[tx_powermail_pi1][uid1517]
```

but it doesn't output anything. How is the correct syntax?

Comment: GPvar: is deprecated, that's why I used GP:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GP:stuff|key` like so:

```
10 = TEXT
10.data = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|uid1517
```

See: http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.5.0/view/1/2/#id1037388
(search for getText)

Comment: Nice, I also found this link http://www.typo3lexikon.de/index.php?id=108 (in german)